# 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Add' and no extension method 'Add' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

```
public partial class consignmentshop : Form
{
    private Store store = new Store();
    private object FristName;
    private string LastName;

    public consignmentshop()
    { 
        InitializeComponent();
        SetupData();
    }

    private void SetupData()
    {
        store.Vendor.Add(new Vendor { FristName = "bill" ,LastName = "smith"});
        store.Vendor.Add(new Vendor { FristName = "sue", LastName = "smith" });
    }
}


namespace ConsignmetShopLibrary1
{
    public class Store
    {
        public readonly object Vendor ;
        public string  Name { get; set; }
        public List<Vendor> Vendors { get; set; }
        public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
        public Store()
        {
            Vendors = new List<Vendor>();
            Items = new List<Item>();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show the class definitions for `Store` and whatever type `Vendor` is.

Comment: how  to show  store and vendor are class

Comment: vendor has to be collection type to be able to add anything to it.....it seems your vendor is object type

Comment: click F12 on Store type and paste the code here

Comment: public partial class consignmentshop : Form
        {
            private Store store = new Store();
            private object FristName;
            private string LastName;
    
            public consignmentshop()
            { 
                InitializeComponent();
                SetupData();
            }
    
            private void SetupData()
            {
                store.Vendor.Add(new Vendor { FristName = "bill" ,LastName = "smith"});
                store.Vendor.Add(new Vendor { FristName = "sue", LastName = "smith" });
            }  @Viru

Comment: Vendor is a class. This class has to be somewhere in your code. So could you please navigate to the code and show it to us here? Like @Viru already said just click on Vendor and then hit F12 which will lead you directly to the Vendor class

Comment: namespace ConsignmetShopLibrary1
{
    public class Vendor
    {
        public string FristName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public double Commission { get; set; }
        public Vendor()
        {
            Commission = .3;
        }

    }
}  @ManuelZelenka

Comment: you also have to show code in Store class......I think your store class should have something like VendorList....Pls edit your question instead of putting code here in comments

Comment: i have show the code  @Viru

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the class shop:

`public readonly object Vendor;`

I guess what you actually would want to call is `Vendors.Add` instead of `Vendor.Add` what you initially did in your first version of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Vendor, you have to add items in Vendors collection.

```
   void SetupData() { store.Vendors.Add(new Vendor { FristName = "bill" ,LastName = "smith"}); store.Vendors.Add(new Vendor { FristName = "sue", LastName = "smith" }); }
```